# Skip legend entries when using the PlotLegends option in Plot[]

Tags: plotting, legending

(This question seems so basic that I have a hard time believing it hasn't been asked yet, but I couldn't find it, so here goes.)

Is it possible to skip items in the legend when using the `PlotLegends` option in `Plot[]`? For instance:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -1, 1},
 PlotLegends -> {"I want this entry", "But not this one!"}]
```

[image: PlotLegends with extraneous entry]

I could, of course, do something along these lines, but that seems impractical:

```
p1 = Plot[x, {x, -1, 1},
 PlotLegends -> {"I want this entry"}];
p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: PlotLegends without extraneous entry, poor man's solution.]

Comment: use `None` for the one you want to skip: `PlotLegends -> {"I want this entry", None}`

Comment: @egwenesedai thanks! I'm surprised that this isn't more obvious in the documentation, but maybe I was overlooking things.

Comment: it's in the details section in the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html

Comment: @egwenesedai my bad! Thanks for your answer.